# Error Code -8969 Decoding, and AVCC Contents

Tags: compression, rtsp, rtp, video-toolbox

I am writing a RTSP client with Flutter SDK that is also using the Apple VideoToolKit API for the HW decoder. I will refrain from posting code at the moment because I think it would just be easier to explain.

I'm using wireshark to inspect contents and it seems parsing is working correctly. My problem is I can't get the data in the right format for the decoder, hence getting OSStatus (Swift) error code -8969. If someone could please clarify the AVCC format along with the inner payload format expected by the decoder, that would be great.

My decoding is done for one frame at a time. So for each frame I create a new decoding session.

The SPS and PPS value is set to a static value on program startup, and then updated once the server begins sending RTP. I don't parse the sprop-parameter-sets value at the moment, I will add this at a later time.

The below buffer will be the resulting AVCC format for a FU-A RTP payload with 3 slices. Please let me know if there is anything I get wrong here. The 4 byte length is big endian representation. When I create the decoding session in Swift, I consider all of this to be 1 sample.

> [4 byte length][FU identifier slice 1][FU header slice 1][NAL Unit payload slice 1][4 byte length][FU identifier slice 2][FU header slice 2][NAL Unit payload slice 2][4 byte length][FU identifier slice 3][FU header slice 3][NAL Unit payload slice 3]

The length is:

> length = RTSP length field - RTP_HEADER_LEN.

Where the RTP_HEADER_LEN is equal to 12 bytes.

Any guidance appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Update: Removed FU identifier from the buffer and I'm getting more frames decoded, and data for the decoded image buffer, which is a good sign. But still getting lots of failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to HLS, as RTSP is not widely supported. The Swift API isn't really set up to accept decoded images for forming a video, so just switched to something that is widely supported. And even better, the API just works. So setting it up wasn't so bad and it saves time.